# Careers 2.0 Banner: editor settings?

Tags: support, jobs

From which editor is this screenshot and what are the settings used? I quite like this font and color scheme looks interesting.

[image]

Comment: Pure guess: it's not from an IDE; it's done in `mspaint` ;)

Comment: It surely could be just a designed thingy :) But still same font in vim + custom color edits would emulate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably find a font that looks like it (or email SE), then use Color Picker or something similar to get RGB/Hex values. Then make a new theme in your IDE of choice and hope you don't get a headache after reading about 750 lines.